# Why height is not calculated correct?

Tags: jquery

```
     <div class="container">
      <div id="freewall">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-tile">

          <a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio.id}">
           ...
          </a>
          <img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" />

          </div>
         <div style="border:1px solid red;">
          <p class="title">${portfolio.title}</p>
          <p class="owner">by ${portfolio.ownerName}</p>
</div>
        </div><!--end grid container-->

        ...repeat container...
        </div>

        </div>
```

JS

```
wall.reset({
                selector: '.grid-designer-container',
                animate: true,
                cellW: 255,
                cellH: 'auto',
                delay: 0,
                gutterY: 15,
                gutterX: 15,
                fixSize: null,
                onResize: function() {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                    wall.refresh();
                    wall.fitHeight(height);
                }
            });

            wall.fitWidth();
```

Using freewall.js to lay out grid. The issue I noticed is that the height is not calculated according to the divs (image and text), resulting in inconsistent gap spacing between the images. Any idea why?

Appreciate help.

**Update**

```
cellH: function(){
    var height = $('grid-container').height();
    return height;
```

It is not working either :(

Comment: removing quote from auto will help.

Comment: @C-link are you referring to `cellH: 'auto'` in OP's js?

Comment: @Dom yes, the OP is using width without quote but using height with quote, so I just guessed only.

Comment: @C-link ya tried that but it is not laid out in grid. see http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/#options

Comment: perhaps: cellH: function (height){return height;}, may works but grid is overlapping which isnt good.

Answer (score 0):

I can see some error in your code. I don't know if its a typo or actual error

But see this function you wrote:

```
cellH: function(){
var height = $('grid-container').height();
return height;
```

In this function you used grid-container like an element but in your html it is a class so by changing your function to below:

```
cellH: function(){
var height = $('.grid-container').height();//adding a dot(.) before grid-container
return height;
```